# Can I change the colour of the ColorColumn in only the current buffer?

Tags: vim

In my ftplugin/python.vim file I have these two lines:

```
setlocal colorcolumn=81
highlight ColorColumn guibg=#222222
```

Which works nicely, but the colour of the column is set globally. Is it possible to set it *only in the current buffer?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can’t. But you can create a workaround: use autocommand that runs on BufEnter event and there check whether you are entering target buffer, altering `hi ColorColumn` in case you are and restoring the value in case you are not. Note though that you can’t have colorcolumns having different colors in different windows, thus this change will recolor all colorcolumns, not just that one displayed in the current window.

Comment: @Codemonkey Better in the question or in the separate answer (or just link specific commit to your vimrc if it is openly hosted on github/bitbucket).